# Riak node not working, but using 100% cpu

Tags: erlang, riak

I configured and started a riak node on a 64bit smp due core cpu machine. However, when I use bin/riak ping to ping the node, it tells me that the node is not responding. But, when I use ps -ef | grep beam, or top, I find that the exact process is existing, and using 100% cpu! The most incomprehensible thing is that the same copy of riak works totally fine on other machines, which has almost the same configuration and system properties.

What exactly is the problem and how to solve?

Comment: You will need to provide more information. But `strace` or `dtruss` the process and try to figure out what it is doing. It suggests a configuration problem.

Comment: Can you please provide the contents of any log files generated when attempting to start the node? You can also attempt to start it up in console mode by using the command `riak console` (http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/running/tools/riak/#console) and attach the output.

Comment: There is NO output. The only observable phenomena is that the CPU is running at 100%, and riak console doesn't response to any input. And this situation can disappear after few minutes, and everything will be OK then. But after another few minutes, the CPU comes back to 100% and the world stops again...

Comment: and strace shows that the process sticks on select system call.

Comment: What OS are you running on? How did you install Riak? Which version of Riak are you using? What is the specification of the server?

Comment: I'm running Riak1.4.2 on RHEL6.1 (VPS) with Erlang R15B01. In fact, after I restarted the VPS, the problem is gone and I don't know why.