# Riak eating 100% CPU on OSX install

Tags: macos, erlang, riak

This question is related to:

[Riak node not working, but using 100% cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077425/riak-node-not-working-but-using-100-cpu)

but since the poster seems to have left I'm posting my case here.

Last night I installed erlang(R15B01) from source, using the config options from the Riak website:

http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.2.1/tutorials/installation/Installing-Erlang/#Installing-on-Mac-OS-X

and Riak(1.4.1) on my 2013 MacBook Pro (2.8GHz i7, 16GB ram, OSX 10.8.3).  I did not change the ulimit, as I assumed it would be fine for a vanilla run.

Installation went fine; warnings but no errors, and I was able to run the toy examples no problem.

However the empty instance quickly ate through all 4 cores and my machine started whining and overheating.

Looking in the logs I see the following error repeated a jillion times:

```
2013-10-11 09:04:04.266 [error]  CRASH REPORT ¥
 Process  with 0 neighbours exited with reason: ¥
 call to undefined function eleveldb:o
```

also tons of crash reports:

```
2013-10-11 09:14:47 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: riak_kv_index_hashtree:init/1
    pid: 
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{undef,[{eleveldb,open,
["./data/anti_entropy/479555224749202520035584085735030365824602865664",
[{create_if_missing,true},{max_open_files,20},{write_buffer_size,12886952}]],[]},
{hashtree,new_segment_store,2,[{file,"src/hashtree.erl"},{line,499}]},{hashtree,new,2,
[{file,"src/hashtree.erl"},{line,215}]},{riak_kv_index_hashtree,do_new_tree,2,
[{file,"src/riak_kv_index_hashtree.erl"},{line,421}]},{lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},
{line,1197}]},{riak_kv_index_hashtree,init_trees,2,[{file,"src/riak_kv_index_hashtree.erl"},
{line,366}]},{riak_kv_index_hashtree,init,1,[{file,"src/riak_kv_index_hashtree.erl"},
{line,226}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]}]},
[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}
    ancestors: [,riak_core_vnode_sup,riak_core_sup,]
    messages: []
    links: []
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 987
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 492
  neighbours:
```

erlang.log says

```
=====
===== LOGGING STARTED Fri Oct 11 09:04:01 CEST 2013
=====
Node 'riak@127.0.0.1' not responding to pings.
config is OK
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 2560; 4096 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
Exec: /tmp/riak-1.4.1/rel/riak/bin/../erts-5.9.1/bin/erlexec 
-boot /tmp/riak-1.4.1/rel/riak/bin/../releases/1.4.1/riak
-config /tmp/riak-1.4.1/rel/riak/bin/../etc/app.config
-pa /tmp/riak-1.4.1/rel/riak/bin/../lib/basho-patches
-args_file /tmp/riak-1.4.1/rel/riak/bin/../etc/vm.args -- console
Root: /tmp/riak-1.4.1/rel/riak/bin/..
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:64]
 [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(riak@127.0.0.1)1>
```

After less than 10m there are already 144MB of logging files with variations of the above.

Comment: i think you might have to re-install your riak, this time, ensure all dependecies are available

Comment: the docs say that eleveldb is included by default, and the riak page provides no further information about how to install it.

Comment: What errors can be found in the error.log file?

Comment: the only one i noticed was the stuff about leveldb missing, at the top of my post.  that is from the error.log.  the details on that are apparently in the crash.log which is the second quote from my above post.  i guess leveldb is not installed for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem by building riak 1.4.6 from source.

I changed in the file etc/app.config the line to

```
{anti_entropy, {off, []}},
```

Leveldb is used by AAE. See the config parameter anti_entropy_leveldb_opts.

Answer (score 0):

Use process of elimination:

> It's hard to say without more information.  Is the 200% being used by
>   `beam.smp`?  Do you see anything in console.log, error.log or crash.log
>   that would indicate something odd is happening?  Are there clients
>   communicating with the cluster at the time?  If so what client/protocol are
>   they using and what types of operations are being performed (e.g.
>   get/put/map reduce/etc)?

**References**

- [Riak consuming too much CPU](http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2011-December/006817.html)
- [Interesting sawtooth increasing CPU usage on lightly-used Riak](http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2011-June/004436.html)
- [Inspecting a Node](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/using/cluster-operations/inspecting-node/)
- [Riak Performance Tuning](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.2.0/cookbooks/Linux-Performance-Tuning/)
- [Open Files Limit](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.2.1/cookbooks/Open-Files-Limit/)
- [Configuration Files](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/configs/configuration-files/)